# Updating WordPress to Version 4.5.1 with Git

Tags: wordpress, git

I currently have WordPress installed as a Git submodule. I'm a bit of a newbie with Git. I've been checking out the latest build using tags in Git. I've noticed that Version 4.5.1 was released on April 26th - however, when I do a pull and fetch on master - Git doesn't recognize a tag for 4.5.1.

I was wondering if this is because the 4.5 branch hasn't merged with master yet or if there's something that I'm doing wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following command from the root git repository:
`git pull --recurse-submodules` will do a pull on all your submodules.

If that won't work for you, you may try running the following command in your root git repository:
`git submodule update --init -- <relative-path-to-submodule>` to update a specific submodule.

Comment: I ran the first command and it says it's up-to-date. I'm wondering though - locally I only have a master branch, but the origin has branches for the various versions. Is there a reason why the other branches in the remote repo aren't appearing as branches on my local repo?

Comment: If you want to checkout to the latest code which is tagged, you can run `git checkout tags/<tag_name>`.

Comment: I figured it out. I think part of it was that I was doing a fetch and pull from within the submodule directory itself rather than doing a submodule update from the root. I basically just needed to do a `git fetch --tags` and `git pull --tags` from within the submodule. Thanks again for your help!